# If I want to start an adwords campaign which should I setup first?

Tags: seo, google, google-analytics, google-ads

It seems to me that there are four topics within this vein:

- Website SEO
- Google Tools for Webmasters
- Google Adwords
- Google Analytics

From what I read in [Google Adwords: A Brave New World](http://www.pagezero.com/publications/google-adwords-guide.php) it sounded like you should really have your SEO, Tools for Webmasters, and GA setup before you start the AdWords Campaign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to monitor the performance of your campaign and get the most out of your advertising spend, you need to do *all* of those things before you start with AdWords.

1. [Sign up for Google Analytics](http://analytics.google.com/) for your site so you can track the progress of other efforts.
2. [Sign up for Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en) - you can use them to identify any problems with your site that Google considers important.
3. [Optimize your site](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-your-sites-position-in-google) (or at least fix everything Webmaster Tools warns you about) - you'll begin reaping the benefits of those efforts immediately, and organic ranking is better than paid ads in many ways.
4. [Sign up for AdWords](https://adwords.google.com/) (and ensure that your campaign links and conversions are tracked in Google Analytics).
5. [Review your Analytics reports](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/16/a-guide-to-google-analytics-and-useful-tools/) and tweak your AdWords campaigns at least once a month to ensure that you are not overspending on keywords which do not convert.

Answer (score 2):

My advice is try to get one of those $50 (50 GBP) vouchers from Google.  Then you feel you are playing with Google's house money.  This probably reflects my personality, but I would just get stuck in, you will make a lot of mistakes, but it does not matter because nobody will know!

The great thing is you get feedback of what works and what doesn't in a day, or a week max.

SEO and html benefit from structured learning, but AdWords - suck it and see.